# Rvalue references in a conditional expression

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, decltype

```
typedef decltype(true ? (long&&)0 : (long&&)0) T;
```

What should T be?

According to gcc (4.7), it's `long`. According to clang (trunk), it's `long&&`. This difference is causing clang to fail to compile code that uses gcc 4.7's libstdc++. Who is right?

**UPDATE**: As **ildjarn** points out, Clang is right, and as **Richard Smith** points out, the error libstdc++ is due to an error in the Standard. Here is the [relevant GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53000), and the [relevant Defect Report](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2141).

Comment: Is this the simplified form of some template code that involves `&&`'s?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes. Is that relevant?

Comment: The main thing I was wondering is if it only happens with basic types, or if it also happens with user-defined ones?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It happens with user-defined types as well.

Comment: libstdc++ contains this error due to an incorrect specification for std::common_type in the C++ standard. There's a patch for libstdc++4.7 on Clang's "C++ status" page to fix this bug: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang is right. N3337 §7.1.6.2/4:

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - **otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`**;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>
> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand.

§5/6:

> [ *Note:* An expression is an xvalue if it is:
>
> - the result of calling a function, whether implicitly or explicitly, whose return type is an rvalue reference to object type,
> - **a cast to an rvalue reference to object type**,
> - a class member access expression designating a non-static data member of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue, or
> - a `.*` pointer-to-member expression in which the first operand is an xvalue and the second operand is a pointer to data member.
>
> In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as lvalues whether named or not. —*end note* ]

I was wary earlier that a literal `0` may somehow prevent this from qualifying as an object type in this context, but §3.9/8 clarifies things:

> An *object type* is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.

The conditional operator doesn't affect anything here – §5.16/4:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

In this case both are of the same value category (xvalue), and xvalues are glvalues.

Comment: The actual example was `typedef decltype(true ? declval<long>() : declval<long>()) T;`, where `declval<T>` returns `T&&`, I just simplified it. Does that change anything?

Comment: @HighCommander4 : Nope, that completely reinforces my argument, as it perfectly matches the first bullet in §5/6.